# Como agrupar por dos fechas en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Buen dia, tengo la siguiente tabla

```
client_acount_id                        amount      created_at
9d2bb89c-372d-11ea-827a-16ec3745526d    29.99   2020-08-03 16:03:38
9d2bb89c-372d-11ea-827a-16ec3745526d    29.99   2020-08-30 10:08:57
9d2bb89c-372d-11ea-827a-16ec3745526d    29.99   2020-09-30 10:09:43
9d2bb89c-372d-11ea-827a-16ec3745526d    29.99   2020-09-30 12:33:45
9d2bb89c-372d-11ea-827a-16ec3745526d    29.99   2020-10-01 10:37:13
9d2bb89c-372d-11ea-827a-16ec3745526d    29.99   2020-10-01 12:34:07
9d2bb89c-372d-11ea-827a-16ec3745526d    29.99   2020-10-02 12:48:54
9d2bb89c-372d-11ea-827a-16ec3745526d    29.99   2020-10-02 14:53:34
9d2bb89c-372d-11ea-827a-16ec3745526d    29.99   2020-10-03 12:56:40
9d2bb89c-372d-11ea-827a-16ec3745526d    29.99   2020-10-03 18:27:28
9d2bb89c-372d-11ea-827a-16ec3745526d    29.99   2020-10-05 10:42:42
9d2bb89c-372d-11ea-827a-16ec3745526d    29.99   2020-10-05 10:42:48
9d2bb89c-372d-11ea-827a-16ec3745526d    29.99   2020-10-05 16:31:00
9d2bb89c-372d-11ea-827a-16ec3745526d    29.99   2020-10-06 12:11:08
9d2bb89c-372d-11ea-827a-16ec3745526d    29.99   2020-10-30 09:10:13
```

Dentro de esta tabla es donde quiero agrupar, lo que pasa es que la empresa tiene su inicio de pagos el dia 6 y su cierre es el 5 del mes siguiente, por lo cual una venta hecha el 2020-10-03, deberia contar en el mes de septiembre, lo cual no he logrado hacer.

He intentando lo siguiente, pero sin resultados.

```
select
    concat(year(t.created_at), '-', month(t.created_at)) month,
    sum(t.amount)
from
    transactions t
where
    t.type_transaction in (1, 2)
    and t.created_at > now() - interval 12 month - interval 6 day
    and client_acount_id = '9d2bb89c-372d-11ea-827a-16ec3745526d'
group by
    month;
```

El cual me agrupa pero solo por el mes, y no por el inicio y cierre de la empresa, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una opción es obtener en una sub-consulta el cálculo del `año-mes` de cada fila o tupla y luego agrupar por allí:

```sql
SELECT
  `der`.`year_month`,
  SUM(`der`.`amount`) `amount`
FROM (
  SELECT
    IF(
      DAY(`created_at`) > 5 /* Start pay day: 6 */,
      DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`, '%Y-%m'),
      DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(`created_at`, INTERVAL -1 MONTH), '%Y-%m')
    ) `year_month`,
    `amount`
  FROM
    `transactions`
  WHERE
    `client_acount_id` = '9d2bb89c-372d-11ea-827a-16ec3745526d'
) `der`
GROUP BY
  `der`.`year_month`
ORDER BY
  `der`.`year_month` DESC;
```

Ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d8a5e72909355ef72faeeea9b1a9e527).

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono perfecto.

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción con MySql 8.0 o superior es utlizar una query recursiva para crear las fechas desde y hasta de cada periodo (de los últimos 12 periodos) y luego vincular con la tabla transactions utilizando dichas fechas. Luego agrupo por fecha periodo desde y sumo las cantidades.

```
WITH RECURSIVE periodos AS (SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 12 MONTH), '-', 
                                            EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 12 MONTH), '-06'), '%Y-%m-%d') AS desde, 
                                STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 11 MONTH), '-', 
                                            EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 11 MONTH), '-05'), '%Y-%m-%d') AS hasta

                         UNION ALL


                         SELECT desde + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, hasta + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
                         FROM periodos
                         WHERE hasta <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)


SELECT CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p.desde), '-', EXTRACT(MONTH FROM p.desde)) AS periodo, 
       ROUND(SUM(t.amount), 2) AS total
FROM periodos p
INNER JOIN transactions t ON DATE(t.created_at) BETWEEN p.desde AND p.hasta
WHERE t.type_transaction in (1, 2)
      AND client_acount_id = '9d2bb89c-372d-11ea-827a-16ec3745526d'
GROUP BY p.desde;
```

Resultado (con los datos de ejemplo de la pregunta):

| periodo | total |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-7 | 29.99 |
| 2020-8 | 29.99 |
| 2020-9 | 329.89 |
| 2020-10 | 59.98 |

Salida de la query recursiva (periodos):

| desde | hasta |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-07-06 | 2020-08-05 |
| 2020-08-06 | 2020-09-05 |
| 2020-09-06 | 2020-10-05 |
| 2020-10-06 | 2020-11-05 |
| 2020-11-06 | 2020-12-05 |
| 2020-12-06 | 2021-01-05 |
| 2021-01-06 | 2021-02-05 |
| 2021-02-06 | 2021-03-05 |
| 2021-03-06 | 2021-04-05 |
| 2021-04-06 | 2021-05-05 |
| 2021-05-06 | 2021-06-05 |
| 2021-06-06 | 2021-07-05 |

Esta es la misma query pero reducida ya que genero solo la fecha desde del periodo:

```
WITH RECURSIVE periodos AS (SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 12 MONTH), '-', 
                                            MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 12 MONTH), '-06'), '%Y-%m-%d') AS desde

                         UNION ALL

                         SELECT desde + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
                         FROM periodos
                         WHERE desde <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)


SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(p.desde), '-', MONTH(p.desde)) AS periodo, 
       ROUND(SUM(t.amount), 2) AS total
FROM periodos p
INNER JOIN transactions t ON DATE(t.created_at) BETWEEN p.desde AND p.desde + INTERVAL 1 MONTH - INTERVAL 1 DAY
WHERE t.type_transaction in (1, 2)
      AND client_acount_id = '9d2bb89c-372d-11ea-827a-16ec3745526d'
GROUP BY p.desde;
```

Combinando tu query con la de @wchiquito:

```
SELECT
      IF(DAY(created_at) > 5, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m'), DATE_FORMAT(created_at - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m')) AS periodo,
      ROUND(SUM(amount), 2) AS total
FROM
    transactions 
    
WHERE
    type_transaction in (1, 2)
    
    AND created_at >= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 12 MONTH), '-', 
                                            MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 12 MONTH), '-06'), '%Y-%m-%d')
    AND created_at <= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '-', 
                                            MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '-05'), '%Y-%m-%d')                                       
                                            
    AND client_acount_id = '9d2bb89c-372d-11ea-827a-16ec3745526d'
    
GROUP BY 
    IF(DAY(created_at) > 5, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m'), DATE_FORMAT(created_at - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m'));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono perfecto, y tu respuesta me ayuda a entender perfectamente.

Comment: De nada @FelipeUrcia! Me alegro que te haya sido util mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Con un `IF`, si el día es menor a 6 lo mandas al periodo anterior.

```
SELECT date_format( if( day(t.created_at) < 6 
                      , t.created_at -interval 6 day
                      , t.created_at
                      ) 
                  , '%y%m'
                  ) periodo_pago
     , sum(t.amount)
  FROM transactions t
  WHERE t.client_acount_id = '9d2bb89c-372d-11ea-827a-16ec3745526d'
    AND t.created_at > now() - interval 12 month
    AND t.type_transaction in (1, 2)
  GROUP BY periodo_pago
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono perfecto tambien.